# Relating to the progressive tense

Tags: progressive-aspect, continuous

Someone started to jump, he was jumping, and he finished jumping, and at intervals, he didn’t do any jumps, so is this situation finally counted as ‘he jumped **once**’?

Progressive: a verb tense that is used to refer to an action or a state that is continuing to happen

Technically, ‘an action is continuing to happen’ means there is one action. Likewise, we don’t say ‘a person is continuing to exist’ means there are several people. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Can you edit to explain the situation a bit more? If someone started to jump, carried on, and then stopped I would have thought that implied they had jumped multiple times in between.

Comment: Because your example could apply equally to a child jumping off a step, a ski jumper leaving the ramp or a skydiver leaping from a plane, it's impossible to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: @mdewey I’ve edited. :)

Comment: A person 'continuing to jump' is probably making a series of jumps.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you!